# Getting Network is unreachable on IPV6 Network

Tags: java, ipv6, httpconnection, oracle-maf

I am getting "Network is Unreachable" from below Java Http request for any url.

Below code is working fine with IPV4 network.

```
                       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                       conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                       conn.setDoOutput(true);
                       conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                       if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                               throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                                               + conn.getResponseCode());
                       }

                       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                               (conn.getInputStream())));


                       System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                       while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                               System.out.println(output);
                       }

                       conn.disconnect();

                 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                       e.printStackTrace();

                 } catch (IOException e) {


                       e.printStackTrace();

                 }
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: There was a bug in Java IPv6 support, [JDK-8015415](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8015415). Try upgrading your JRE.

Comment: Did anyone find any answer?

Answer (score -1):

If you are specifying the IPv6 URL using the IP address, you need to enclose it in square brackets since the `::` in the address are special characters in a URL.

See [RFC 2732](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt).

Comment: If this was the issue, OP would get an `UnknownHostException`, not a "Network is Unreachable"